# Jenkins pipeline get "No such property" with pipeline library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

In my shared libraries,  I define:

vars/checkoutSvnCode.groovy

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy    
//get svn code    
def call(String URL="url") {
    def scmVars = checkout([
        $class: 'SubversionSCM',
        additionalCredentials: [],
        excludedCommitMessages: '',
        excludedRegions: '',
        excludedRevprop: '',
        excludedUsers: '',
        filterChangelog: false,
        ignoreDirPropChanges: false,
        includedRegions: '',
        locations: [[
            cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true,
            credentialsId: 'svn_auth',
            depthOption: 'infinity',
            ignoreExternalsOption: true,
            local: '.',
            remote: "${URL}"
        ]],
        quietOperation: false,
        workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']
    ])
    def REVISION = scmVars.SVN_REVISION
    println "//Revision：\"${REVISION}\""
}
```

In my pipeline, I define

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Library('jenkins-pipeline-library')_
import com.test.GlobalVars

    pipeline {    
        environment {
            def SVN_ADDR = "svn://code.test.com/myproject"
        }
        
        agent any
        
        stages {
            
            stage('getCode') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        checkoutSvnCode("${SVN_ADDR}")
                        println "//Revision：\"${REVISION }\""
                    }
                }
            }
    
        }
    }
```

now I get this error

> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: REVISION for
> class: groovy.lang.Binding

how can I get the "REVISION" in my pipeline?

Comment: The `REVISION` variable is not declared or initialized in your Pipeline, so you cannot resolve its value. That is why the error is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in the curley braces for your REVISION var ${REVISION } should be ${REVISION}

Comment: oh,is a syntax error, without this space, I  still get the same error  "No such property: REVISION"

Answer (score 0):

You define REVISION in the groovy library file, that gets called from your pipeline process and then terminates.  I am no groovy expert, but the normal behaviour of a calling script calling a process that terminates is that all the values in the child process (library file) disappear when the sub-process completes.  The problem seems to be that your pipeline process can't access the variable in your library file.

Have you thought of using the Jenkins Environment Variable: SVN_REVISION ?

${SVN_REVISION} should have it for you - can you try :

```
println "//Revision：\"${SVN_REVISION}\""
```

Else, it should be in the jenkins file, or, worst case scenario get it from shelling to the command:

```
svn info --show-item revision
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also have your `checkoutSvnCode` DSL function RETURN the revision and then:

```
        stage('getCode') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def REVISION = checkoutSvnCode("${SVN_ADDR}")
                    println "//Revision：\"${REVISION}\""
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks, I solved this problem with the "return" function

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this problem

vars/checkoutSvnCode.groovy

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy    
//get svn code    
def call(String URL="url") {
    def scmVars = checkout([
        $class: 'SubversionSCM',
        additionalCredentials: [],
        excludedCommitMessages: '',
        excludedRegions: '',
        excludedRevprop: '',
        excludedUsers: '',
        filterChangelog: false,
        ignoreDirPropChanges: false,
        includedRegions: '',
        locations: [[
            cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true,
            credentialsId: 'svn_auth',
            depthOption: 'infinity',
            ignoreExternalsOption: true,
            local: '.',
            remote: "${URL}"
        ]],
        quietOperation: false,
        workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']
    ])
    return scmVars
}
```

In pipeline

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Library('jenkins-pipeline-library')_
import com.test.GlobalVars

    pipeline {    
        environment {
            def SVN_ADDR = "svn://code.test.com/myproject"
        }
        
        agent any
        
        stages {
            
            stage('getCode') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        def REVISION = checkoutSvnCode("${SVN_ADDR}").SVN_REVISION
                        println "//Revision：\"${REVISION }\""
                    }
                }
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Now I can get the SVN_REVISION successfully ^_^

> //Revision："39128"